# ¿cómo evitar la pirámide de la muerte en Angular2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, observable

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo que realizar 2 llamadas a una API REST, para cada llamada tengo un servicio o metodo correspondiente de la clase que actua como servicio, el problema es que la segunda para ejecutarse requiere un parametro que es devuelto por el primero osea tiene que esperar que se ejecute el primer servicio para poder llamarse, mi pregunta radica en como aplicar los observables para que el código quede limpio sin tener que recurrir a la pirámide de la muerte.

Para los que no sepan que es una piramide de la muerte en JS es algo asi:

```
obj.metodo1(data, function(dato1) { 
    obj.metodo2(data, function(dato2) {
        obj.metodo3(data, function(dato3) { 
            obj.metodo4(data, function(dato4) {
                //Hasta terminar la cantidad de consultas que tenemos 
                //que realizar
            });
        });
    });
});
```

El metodo4 depende de que el metodo3 se ejecute, este a su ves depende de que se ejecute antes el metodo2 y este al mismo tiempo depende para ejecutarse del metodo1.

Entenderán el problema que esto acarrea, y bueno recordando entre las características de Angular2 se proponía una forma mas amigable de lidiar con este problema.

Gracias

Comment: Una palabra, muchos sentimientos **Promesas**

Comment: Si exactamente pregunto como implementarlas

Comment: Si alguna respuesta pudo resolver el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto seria un ejemplo con promesas:

```
getAnimales(): Promise<Animal[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.animalesUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
        response => response.json() as Animal[])
        //aqui puedes llamar a la  otra Api

    .catch(this.handleError);
    }
        private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('Ha Ocurrido Un Error', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```